# Aggregate rows within group meeting condition using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table in the following format:

```
Sample     Location     Phylum           Abundance
1          Teat canal   Firmicutes       0.34
1          Teat canal   Actinobacteria   0.26
1          Teat canal   Candidatus       0.001
1          Teat canal   Chloroflexi      0.001
2          Teat canal   Firmicutes       0.30
2          Teat canal   Actinobacteria   0.24
2          Teat canal   Apicomplexa      0.005
2          Teat canal   Chloroflexi      0.001
```

I want to **(1)** calculate the mean abundance of each phyla within each location; and **(2)** rename + concatenate phyla with a mean abundance less than 0.01 into a separate category called Other using dplyr. To start, I did the following:

```
phym %>%
  group_by(Location, Phylum) %>%
  summarise(MeanAbundance = mean(Abundance)) %>%
  mutate(Phylum = ifelse(MeanAbundance < 0.01, "Other", levels(Phylum)[Phylum]))
```

This will calculate mean abundances for each phyla within each location and rename phyla with a mean abundance less than 0.01 to Other. How can I augment this code to concatenate abundance values for the Other category within each location (assuming multiple, different locations)?

Comment: Hi @Christopher Dean - it would be great if you provide (for this example) how the final result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to group by 'Location', 'Phylum', create the 'MeanAbundance' column with `mutate`, then grouped by 'Location', `summarise` by concatenating the `unique` 'Phylum' where the 'MeanAbundance' is less than 0.01 into a single string (`toSTring`), similarly, the levels converted 'Other' is also concatenated in 'Phylum'

```
library(dplyr)
phym %>%
    group_by(Location, Phylum) %>%
    mutate(MeanAbundance = mean(Abundance)) %>%
    group_by(Location) %>%
    summarise(Othergroup = toString(unique(Phylum[MeanAbundance < 0.01])),
            Phylum = toString(unique(ifelse(MeanAbundance < 0.01, 
                  "Other", levels(Phylum)[Phylum]))))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#Location   Othergroup                           Phylum                           
#   <chr>      <chr>                                <chr>                            
#1 Teat canal Candidatus, Chloroflexi, Apicomplexa Firmicutes, Actinobacteria, Other
```

#### data

```
phym <- structure(list(Sample = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
 Location = c("Teat canal", 
"Teat canal", "Teat canal", "Teat canal", "Teat canal", "Teat canal", 
"Teat canal", "Teat canal"), Phylum = structure(c(5L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Actinobacteria", "Apicomplexa", 
"Candidatus", "Chloroflexi", "Firmicutes"), class = "factor"), 
    Abundance = c(0.34, 0.26, 0.001, 0.001, 0.3, 0.24, 0.005, 
    0.001)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```